# When an operator/matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional (n-dimensional) vector space $V$ over a field $K.$ Suppose $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to a given basis for $V$. We can see that the following statements are equivalent:

0. $T$ is invertible.
1. $T$ is an injection ie. the kernel of $T$ is trivial.
2. $T$ is a surjection.
3. $T$ is a bijection.
4. The rank of the matrix/ rank of the operator/dimension of the image of $T$ is $n$.
5. The determinant of $T$ is non-zero i.e. $T$ is not singular.
6. All the column vectors of $T$ are linearly independent.
7. None of the eigenvectors of $T$ is zero.
8. $T$ maps any set of independent vectors into another set of independent vectors.
9. There exists a natural number m such that $det(T^m) \neq 0.$
10. dim (range $T$) = rank($T$) = dim($V$).
11. The reduced row echelon form of $A$ is $I_n.$
12. The equation $T(x)=0$ has only one solution namely $0.$
13. $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for any given vector $b$.
14. The span of the columns of $A$= column space = $K^n.$
15. The span of rows of $A$= row space of $A$= $K^n.$
16. There exists an $(n\times n)$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_n = BA.$
17. The transpose of $A$ namely $A^t$ is invertible.
18. The matrix $A$ can be expressed as a finite product of elementary matrices.

This list can be extended. I can clearly see their equivalence. Using three basic concepts:
(a) the rank-nullity theorem/dimension theorem,
(b) $det(AB)= det(A) det(B)$, and
(c) $det(A)$= product of eigenvalues of $T$
one can easily prove the equivalence of these statements. Now, could you provide some "less obvious" statements which are also equivalent to the invertibility of $T$? Thank you for your time.
Thanks so much.

Comment: "There exists a matrix $B$ such that $BA = I$" and "There exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB = I$" are two more such statements

Comment: What do you mean "less obvoius"? A statement can be true or not, and how obvious it is is quite subjectively. I'm not sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: If $V$ is a normed space, then we also have "$T$ is bounded away from zero", i.e. there exists a $c>0$ for which $\|Tx\| > c\|x\|$ for all $x \in V$.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I mean some equivalence which we don't see often. Probably something which requires a little more arguments, rather than the straightforward application of dimension theorem.

Comment: When $V$ is an inner-product space, you also have some statements related to when exactly the polar decomposition is unique.  For instance, with the solution to the [orthogonal procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), we find that $A$ is invertible if and only if there is a unique "nearest orthogonal neighbor," i.e. a unique orthogonal matrix $U$ that minimizes the Frobenius distance $\|A - U\|_F$.

Comment: @ Ben Thanks so much.

Comment: If you're into topology, there's the classic "$T$ is an open map" or "$T$ is a homeomorphism".

Comment: Such a $\;T\;$ is invertible iff zero is **not** one of its eigevalues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling statements into a community wiki answer that can be expanded.

Topology / Norms, $T$ is invertible iff:

1. $T$ is bounded below, meaning for any norm on the space there is a $C$ so that $\|T v\|≥ C\|v\|$ for all vectors $v$.
2. $T$ is an open map.
3. For any linear map $A$ there is an $\epsilon >0$ so that $T+ rA$ is invertible (ie satisfies any of the other criteria) for all $|r|≤\epsilon$.

Consider a scalar product $(,)$ on the vector space. Call a decomposition $T=UA$ with $U$ unitary and $A≥0$ a polar decomposition. $T$ is invertible iff:

1. The unitary in the polar decomposition is unique.
2. $A$ in the polar decomposition is strictly positive, ie $(x,Ax)\neq0$ for all $x\neq0$.

Algebra, $T$ is invertible iff:

1. The linear map $L_T: \mathrm{End}(V)\to\mathrm{End}(V)$, $A\mapsto TA$ is invertible. The same for the map $R_T(A)=AT$.
2. The ideal $\{ TAT\mid A\in\mathrm{End}(V)\}$ is all of $\mathrm{End}(V)$.
3. One has $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho T^*T)>0$ for any non-zero matrix $\rho≥0$.

Comment: Thank you so much.